# Animate SVG element after changing it on the fly

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

Internet Explorer does not support `beginElement` for SVG animations, so I am looking for a workaround. My aim is to string together a series of animations, under user control.  Below is a demo that shows two animations to simulate stages in blowing up a balloon. If you click on the smaller balloon after its first animation

- In Chrome, Firefox and Opera: it jumps to the final stage of the second animation ()
- In Safari: it shows the start of the animation but never animates
- In Internet Explorer: I don't get any animation at all

Is there a cross-platform technique I can use to create a sequence of animations, where the user must intervene between each animation?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 250 250">

  <defs>
    <path id="one"
        d="M 0 95 l 30 0 A 20 15 30 1 1 30 105 l -30 0 z"
        fill="blue">
     <animate
        attributeName="d"
        attributeType="XML"
        from="M 0 95 l 30 0 A 20 15 30 1 1 30 105 l -30 0 z"
            to="M 0 95 l 30 0 A 25 20 0 1 1 30 105 l -30 0 z"
        dur="1s"
        fill="freeze" />
      </path>


    <path id="two"
        d="M 0 95 l 30 0 A 25 20 0 1 1 30 105 l -30 0 z"
        fill="blue">
      <animate
        attributeName="d"
        attributeType="XML"
        from="M 0 95 l 30 0 A 25 20 0 1 1 30 105 l -30 0 z"
            to="M 0 95 l 30 0 A 50 40 0 1 1 30 105 l -30 0 z"
        dur="1s"
        fill="freeze" />
    </path>
  </defs>

  <use id="a" xlink:href="#one"/> 
  <use xlink:href="#two" transform="rotate(180 125 125)"/> 
</svg>

<script>
  var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  var use = document.querySelector("#a")

  use.onmouseup = inflate

  function inflate() {
    use.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, "xlink:href", "#two")
  }
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0gmdus9/)

Answer (score 0):

Intenet Explorer doesn't support SMIL animation at all.

The usual recommended workaround for IE is to use the [Fakesmile library](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) which adds SMIL support to IE.  It supports `beginElement()`.

Answer (score -3):

I would strongly recommend [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/)

Edit: SVG is powerful and complex. Snap.svg gives you a ton of control over your svg animations whether they're created dynamically or with a tool like Adobe Illustrator or Sketch. It's a cross-browser solution written by the same person that wrote Raphael (another svg animation library)

It makes things really easy and is quite awesome to use. So instead of fiddling around with what you've got I would strongly recommend getting your hands on Snap.svg. At least follow the link and check it out. Very cool!

Comment: For this to qualify as an answer you'd need to explain how snap can solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'm using SVG to create really really small standalone HTML files, so adding 78 KB of overhead is not a high priority. I prefer to understand what minimum steps I can make in pure JavaScript to get this to work.

Comment: This was originally supposed to be a comment but that's not allowed due to my low rep. So can anyone help me understand why this is the case? I'm getting down voted for posting an answer but I can't post a comment... catch 22 going on here...